# Angular JS validation not Working in CSHTML(Razor)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate input controls in cshtml using AngularJS. It is not working in CSHTML, but it does work in normal HTML pages. Is there any way to solve the issue?

My code is something like the following:

```
  <form ng-app novalidate ng-submit="addRow()">
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" required />
            <span class="text-danger" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
            <span class="text-danger" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your ng-class is not correct.Instead of submitted, put formName.$submitted and don't forget to add form name to your form tag

Comment: You should add `name` attribute to `form` element like `name="form"`, Also I don't find a place where you had toggled `submitted` flag..

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="addRow()">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email" required />
      <span data-ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required  && (myForm.email.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Required.</span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you post your entire csHtml code without missing a character..?